# How can I define a while loop as a higher-order function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am facing the following problem, could someone give me some hints? thanks so much!

Define higher-order function `while`, in which the condition and the operation work over values of type `a`. Its type should be

```
whileG :: (a -> IO Bool) -> (a -> IO a) -> (a ->IO a)
```

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: @DanielVelkov I have no idea on it..

Comment: There are wonderful tutorials on Haskell in general and IO in particular floating around the web. Perhaps you should work your way through one or two and try again.

Comment: @Justin take a look at the functions in http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Monad.html

Answer (score 5):

In a language like haskell you will not necessarily need loops. If you do then that means you are trying to implement your idea in an imperative way which is not always the right thing to do.

Just to cut it short, as I have no idea of what you are doing, you can look at [loops](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/monad-loops/0.3.0.2/doc/html/Control-Monad-Loops.html) library which defines several such loops.

Comment: I disagree with the assertion that Control.Monad.Loops is not "Haskellish". All of these functions come in extremely handy when working with monadic code, and particularly unfoldM is a very "functional" type of looping function.

Comment: @Wes Ok, maybe my language was wrong. We have Control.Monad.Loops because people need  that, but I meant that you should not always try to use loops as in the case of imperative languages.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is one of the exercises in Simon Thompson's book The Craft of Functional Programming.  I also struggled with this problem and this is what I came up with, which in no way do I claim is the best answer, but might offer at least a hint.

```
whileG :: (a -> IO Bool) -> (a -> IO a) -> (a -> IO a)
whileG testIO action x = do
    test <- testIO x
    if test
    then do
        y <- action x
        whileG testIO action $ y
    else return x
```

I am assuming here that some computation is done in each iteration of the 'loop' and that result of this computation, which has type a, is input to both the testIO function (to check whether or not the loop invariant still holds) and to the action in the next iteration.

Comment: Why the `$` in the recursive invocation?